# Reading File and Inserting into Variables using Perl

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl, so please bare with my on my ignorance.  What I'm trying to do is read a file (already using File::Slurp module) and create variables from the data in the file. Currently I have this setup:

```
use File::Slurp;
my @targets = read_file("targetfile.txt");
print @targets;
```

Within that target file, I have the following bits of data:

> id:   123456789
>
> name: anytownusa
>
> 1.2.3.4/32
>
> 5.6.7.8/32

The first line is an ID, the second line is a name, and all successive lines will be IP addresses (maximum length of a few hundred).

So my goal is to read that file and create variables that look something like this:

```
$var1="123456789";

$var2="anytownusa";

$var3="1.2.3.4/32,5.6.7.8/32,etc,etc,etc,etc,etc";
```

** Taking note that all the IP addresses end up grouped together into a single variable and seperated by a (,) comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been noted, there is no reason to "*slurp*" the whole file into a variable. If nothing else, it only makes the processing *harder*. 
Also, why not store named labels in a hash, in this example

```
my %identity = (id => 123456789, name => 'anytownusa');
```

The code below picks up the key names from the file, they aren't hard-coded.

Then

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my (@ips, %identity);

my $file = 'targetfile.txt';
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

while (<$fh>) 
{
    next if not /\S/;
    chomp;

    my ($m1, $m2) = split /:/;                #/(stop bad syntax highlight)

    if ($m1 and $m2) { $identity{$m1} = $m2; }
    else             { push @ips, $m1;       }
}

say "$_: $identity{$_}" for keys %identity;

say join '/', @ips;
```

If the line doesn't have `:` the [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) will return it whole, which will be the ip and which is stored in an array for processing later. Otherwise it returns the named pair, for `'id'` and `'name'`.

We first skipped blank lines with `next if not /\S/;`, so the line must have some non-space elements and `else` suffices, as there is always something in `$m1`.  We also need to remove the newline, with [chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html).

Comment: The target file changes, so the id, name, and IPs are always new. How would you adjust this code for that?

Comment: @Alby Do you mean that the values/names change? That is the main point of this approach.  It reads _anything_ with `:` and picks its "name" and "value" -- whatever the "name" is.  For a single entry on a line (when there is no `:` on the line)  it just takes it and puts it in an array.  It doesn't matter whether those are mixed, on what lines which ones are, or what they are called.

Comment: Thanks.. Yes, just the values change. The word "id:" and "name:" remain the same, but the values change along with the IPs.

Comment: @Alby OK. This reads the file anew every time it runs, and picks up what is there as it reads it.  As for `id` and `name` -- it gets them every time, which is fine. (And is not relying on line numbers, is not bothered by empty lines etc).  Also, if they were to change, or new such items added, it will still work.

Comment: I got a couple of errors in the coding.  Suggestions? syntax error at ztest.pl line 20, near "%identity{"
syntax error at ztest.pl line 22, near "else"
Global symbol "$m1" requires explicit package name at ztest.pl line 23.

Comment: @Alby  Oh ... sorry, that was a typo -- it should be `$identity{$m1}`, NOT with `%`. It's a hash value, which is a scalar, thus needs a `$`.  Changed in the post.  The other one is because of this first one.

Comment: Worked like a charm..  Thanks:   ztest.pl syntax OK

Comment: Can somebody please vote up my question? I seem to have run into a scoring-posting issue and need more good Up votes. ;-)

Comment: @Alby  I didn't even know there was such a limit.  The idea is probably to force people to post "good" questions -- a lot of not-so-good ones take/abuse bandwidth and attention.  So I'd suggest: study thoughtfully all your previous questions and people's comments, to see how to improve them. Then the future ones will get upvotes.  (I am not accusing you of any wrongdoing! Just trying to suggest a constructive course of action.)

Comment: @Alby  See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center, and think through it carefully.  One critical component of "good" questions is that the authors first researched the existing Q/A carefully.  Very often you'll find your answer, and if not you will _certainly_ find very closely related material.  Working through those will either make you figure it out, or it will make your following question far better.  It doesn't take very long to locate a handful of very related questions.  I don't mean to criticize you with this, just trying to help out.

Answer (score 3):

`File::Slurp` will read the complete file data in one go. This might cause an issue if the file size is very big. Let me show you a simple approach to this problem.

1. Read file line by line using while loop
2. Check line number using `$.` and assign line data to respective variable
3. Store ips in an array and at the end print them using `join`

Note: If you have to alter the line data then use search and replace in the respective conditional block before assigning the line data to the variable.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my ($id, $name, @ips);

while(<DATA>){
    chomp;
    if ($. == 1){
        $id = $_;   
    }
    elsif ($. == 2){
        $name = $_;
    }
    else{
        push @ips, $_;  
    }
}

print "$id\n";
print "$name\n";
print join ",", @ips;

__DATA__
id: 123456789
name: anytownusa
1.2.3.4/32
5.6.7.8/32
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/YeqCZF)

Comment: How would I make $id and $name only output 123456789 and anytownusa?  Excluding the id: and name: fields?

Comment: As I said, use search and replace to alter the data. `$id =~ s/id: //g` and `$name =~ s/name: //g` would do.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into variables directly:

```
use Modern::Perl;

my ($id, $name, @ips) = (<DATA>,<DATA>,<DATA>);
chomp ($id, $name, @ips);
say $id;
say $name;
$" = ',';
say "@ips";

__DATA__
id: 123456789
name: anytownusa
1.2.3.4/32
5.6.7.8/32
```

**Output:**

```
id: 123456789
name: anytownusa
1.2.3.4/32,5.6.7.8/32
```

Comment: How does my ($id, $name, @ips) = (<DATA>,<DATA>,<DATA>);  read in the file?  Lets say the file is called target.txt.

Comment: @Alby:`<DATA>` is used to read the data after `_DATA_`. To read your real file, you have to open it first, the replace `<DATA>` by the filehandle `<$FILEHANDLE>`